# crosstab function is not accessible to non-postgres users

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions

I've installed tablefuncs via create extension tablefuncs and can use crosstab from the postgres account.  However, its not visible/usable to non-postgres users.

From postgres account:

```
\dx
                                 List of installed extensions
   Name    | Version |   Schema   |                        Description
-----------+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql   | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 tablefunc | 1.0     | public     | functions that manipulate whole tables, including crosstab
(2 rows)
```

From non-postgres users:

```
abxdb=> set search_path to abx, public;
SET
abxdb=> \dx
                                         List of installed extensions
       Name       | Version |   Schema   |                             Description
------------------+---------+------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
 plpgsql          | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgis          | 2.0.7   | public     | PostGIS geometry, geography, and raster spatial types and functions
 postgis_topology | 2.0.7   | topology   | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions
```

This is the example I'm trying to run:

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id int,
  key text,
  value text
);

INSERT INTO example VALUES
  (123, 'firstName', 'John'),
  (123, 'lastName', 'Doe');


SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT *
     FROM example
     ORDER BY id ASC, key ASC;'
) AS ct(id INT, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT);
```

I've tried creating the extension in the non-postgres account, but it must be created under postgres.

Comment: I see no error message. Check the `search_path`.

Comment: It is not the different user which is tripping you up, but the different database.  The extension must be created in every database where you want to use it.

Comment: the different database comment was the problem.  I was logging in with postgres to the postgres database.